# Need help with Rspec example

Tags: ruby, rspec, automated-tests, watir, watir-webdriver

Can any one have more descriptive example of Rspec? I used the the example from site https://gist.github.com/1053934 works very fine. But i want to learn more like go to site X (eg. Google) -> enter data in text field (eg. Ruby)
Check for the HTML is Ruby available in the list?

Can any one have script that i can run on Rspec and that will generate report on that pass fail status of case.

I appreciate all the responses in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a complete example, courtesy of [Watir docs](http://watir.com/frameworks/).

```
require "rubygems"
require "rspec"

describe "google.com" do
  let(:browser)       { @browser ||= Watir::Browser.new :firefox }

  before { browser.goto "http://google.com" }
  after  { browser.close }

  it "should search for watir" do
    browser.text_field(:name => "q").set "watir"
    browser.button.click
    browser.div(:id => "resultStats").wait_until_present
    browser.title.should == "watir - Google Search"
  end
end
```

Comment: I guess they were trying to be concise, but personally I'd use do/end blocks for the before and after clauses.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Also have some other issue with watir  rspec and xpath. As i am using the xpath for locating the elements. But some time watir detects the element and some time id does not. How can i fix that prob. As i have to use xpath because HTML is not very high standard some of the element missing the id and/or name. I am using xpather of firefox to generate the xpath of the element

Comment: Please post a new question instead of a comment